# On the quality of triangles in triangulations

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, triangles, triangulation

By indicating respectively with $\theta_{\min}$ and $\theta_{\max}$ the minimum angle and the maximum angle of a triangle, we have:

$$
\text{quality}(\theta_{\min},\,\theta_{\max}) := \max\left(\frac{\pi/3-\theta_{\min}}{\pi/3},\,\frac{\theta_{\max}-\pi/3}{2\,\pi/3}\right)
$$

that is a function with image the interval $[0,\,1]$ that tries to give an indication about the goodness of a triangle.

In particular, we obtain $0$ in the case of equilateral triangles, $1$ in the case of degenerate triangles.

At this point, I was wondering if it was possible to get the same function, but in terms of $\cos\theta_{\min}$, $\cos\theta_{\max}$.

I tried to modify the function in the following way:

$$
\text{quality}(\theta_{\min},\,\theta_{\max}) := \max\left(\frac{1/2-\cos\theta_{\min}}{1/2},\,\frac{\cos\theta_{\max}-1/2}{-1/2}\right)
$$

but obviously the same values are not obtained, the image set is different!

Some advice? Thank you!

Comment: See also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27090/commonly-used-metrics-to-quantify-the-irregularity-of-a-triangular-mesh and https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-03-01485-6

Comment: Is this in connection with Delaunay triangulation ?

Comment: @Ihf: thanks, I will read everything carefully.

Comment: @Jean Marie: let's say yes, even if at the moment I am taking my first steps in the world of triangulation, let's say that I am in the phase in which I would like to understand a little more.